# Use Cosine Similarity with Binary Data - Mahout

Tags: mahout, binary-data, similarity, mahout-recommender, cosine-similarity

I have a boolean/binary where a customer and product id are found when the customer actually bought the product and not found if the customer did not buy it. The dataset represented like this:

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN5SY.png)

I have tried different approaches like GenericBooleanPrefUserBasedRecommender with TanimotoCoefficient or LogLikelihood similarities, but I have also tried GenericUserBasedRecommender with the Uncentered Cosine Similarity and it gave me the highest precision and recall 100% and 60% respectively.

I am not sure if it makes sense to use the Uncentered Cosine Similarity in this situation, or this is a wrong logic ? and what does the Uncentered Cosine Similairty do with such dataset.

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100% precision is impossible so something is wrong. All the similarity metrics work fine with boolean data. Remember the space is of very high dimensionality.

Your sample data only has two items (BTW ids should be 0 based for the old hadoop version of Mahout). So the dataset as shown is not going to give valid precision scores.

I've done this with large E-Com datasets and Log-likelihood considerably out-performs the other metrics on boolean data.

BTW Mahout has moved on to Spark from Hadoop and our only metric is LLR. A full Universal Recommender with event store and prediction server based on Mahout-Samsara is implemented here:
http://templates.prediction.io/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-universal-recommendation
Slides describing it here: http://www.slideshare.net/pferrel/unified-recommender-39986309

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't have a problem with the high dimensionality, since my data is not that huge, I have only around 3000 rows and I am using SAP HANA which is in-memory computing DB. 

I thought so too, that the precision can never be 100%, my biggest concern is always related to the representation of the data, since I have all the preferences 1. Is it ok to represent the boolean data like that, or should I include the products which the customers did not buy and set it to 0 ? Maybe you can provide me with an example for a binary dataset, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Using the Universal Recommender any item the user does not interact with is assumed 0. All you need to do is send interaction events to the recommender tied to a user, train on the data periodically, then query by user or item id. No need for id translation like the old Mahout code, and no need to enumerate all users of items. These are detected from the interaction data. Also you can use many events, even user profile data.